# SQL query to subtract multiple dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a report/query on a "machinery_table" with input parameters - site, machine_part, from_date and to_date (DD/MM/YYYY)

The data exists in this table as -

Site | Machine_part | Old_status | New_status | Journal_date

```
London, Ship1, OOP, IO, 04/06/2023 
London, Ship1, IO, OOP, 03/05/2023
London, Ship1, OOP, IO, 04/04/2023 
London, Ship1, IO, OOP, 03/03/2023
```

I need to write it such that the difference between the dates of when it was "OOP" (OUT OF OPERATION) and "IO" (IN OPERATION) is derived for all those days that fall within the date input parameters and the "out of operation hours" is added up for all the lines within the parameter range.

I tried custom functions but I am not sure how to add them for all the lines

Answer (score 0):

Try that query

```
SELECT 
    Site, 
    Machine_part, 
    SUM(OutageHours) AS Total_Outage_Hours
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Site, 
        Machine_part, 
        Journal_date, 
        LAG(Journal_date) OVER (PARTITION BY Site, Machine_part ORDER BY Journal_date) AS Prev_Journal_date, 
        New_status, 
        CASE 
            WHEN New_status = 'OOP' THEN 
                (Journal_date - LAG(Journal_date) OVER (PARTITION BY Site, Machine_part ORDER BY Journal_date)) * 24
            ELSE 0
        END AS OutageHours
    FROM machinery_table
    WHERE 
        Site = :site
        AND Machine_part = :machine_part
        AND Journal_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(:from_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:to_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
)
GROUP BY Site, Machine_part;
```